# set the auto width to the thumbnail of the royal slider jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am using the royal slider plugin. I want to give the thumbnail image width as auto. and the active pointer(.rsNavItem .rsThumb .rsNavSelected) width should be auto or the size of the corresponding image. Any one can help? please!

Comment: Please any one help? Its a high priority issue for me

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in my code

```
.rsNavItem .rsThumb .rsNavSelected {
        width: auto !important;
 }
```

The JS is adding inline `css` hence the `!important`